# What is the Rust way to deal with constant math when we only have a generic trait

Tags: math, rust, traits

Here is my broken example code. Note that I just want to double the value and allow anything which knows how to multiply.

```rust
fn by_two<T: Mul<Output = T>>(x: T) -> T {
    x * 2
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue you are running into is you needs to say what you are multiplying with. `2` defaults to an `<integer>` which if unspecified counts as an `i32`, so here is that example:

```rust
fn by_two<T: Mul<i32, Output=T>>(x: T) -> T {
    x * 2
}
```

Alternatively, you could just leave the result up to the trait. This is generally* equivalent to just using `x * 2` without calling the function.

```rust
fn by_two<T: Mul<i32>>(x: T) -> <T as Mul<i32>>::Output {
    x * 2
}
```

However, this won't work with most types since Rust usually expects primitives to be multiplied with other privatives of the same type. We could change it to use `From<i32>` to make it more inclusive.

```rust
fn by_two<T: Mul + From<i32>>(x: T) -> <T as Mul>::Output {
    x * T::from(2)
}
```

At this point you may be noticing the problem. We need to figure out what type "2" is so it can multiply with `T`. The `From<i32>` solution works well for primitive types, but you will start to run into difficulties if you tried to plug a vector or matrix into the function. One solution would be to add a separate generic to allow the user to specify what it gets multiplied with.

```rust
fn by_two<T: Mul<K>, K: From<i32>>(x: T) -> <T as Mul<K>>::Output {
    x * K::from(2)
}
```

However, this is starting to get a bit cumbersome. Unlike the previous versions, we can't let the compiler infer a type to use for `K` since there might be multiple types which could satisfy the requirements put on `K`.

One option which doesn't quite solve our problem, but may help us a bit would be to use a crate like [`num-traits`](https://crates.io/crates/num-traits). Though to be honest, this really just amounts to more or less the same thing as example 2, but with a more generalized concept of 2.

```rust
use num_traits::identities::One;
fn by_two<T: One + Add<Output=T>>(x: T) -> T {
    x * (T::one() + T::one())
}
```

You have a ton of options, but none are all inclusive. If you want to keep your match as generic as possible, you are probably best off writing the function first, then determining what mathematical properties the values must satisfy to make it work. You can use [`num-traits`](https://crates.io/crates/num-traits) for basic trait bounds such as differentiating between floats and ints. Then for more complex concepts, I recommend using [`alga`](https://crates.io/crates/alga).

Answer (score 1):

Well... what *is* two? For example, if I define my multiplication on `Color` as mixing two colors, then what does it mean to multiply a color by two?

The easiest way to solve this is by choosing a very small data type that two fits in (such as `u8`) and accepting any `T` which can (try to) convert from `u8`:

```
fn by_two<T: Mul<Output = T> + TryFrom<u8>>(x: T) -> T {
    x * 2.try_into().ok().expect("could not convert two into T")
}
```

The more general (but cumbersome) way is to use the `num` crate, and accept anything that can be multiplied, and has a concept of `One`, using `One + One` as two.

Comment: Is there a runtime penalty for try_into or is this purely a compile time check?

Comment: But my lye say "clean more white than white" .... must mean my cloth become transparent

Comment: @NathanTippy There's a runtime penalty if the conversion can actually fail. For something like `i32` it would completely get optimized out: https://rust.godbolt.org/z/foj67bbs9.

Comment: Thanks! seeing the assembly for different approaches is very helpful. I like to know what is really going to happen under the covers.